# How to add a jQuery filter to a html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, dropdown

I'm trying to put a drop down filter to a html table using JQuery. Here's the code.

report.php

```
<table id ="myTable" class="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th> First Name </th>
                    <th> Last Name </th>                  
                    <th> Phone </th>
                    <th> Email </th>              
                    <th> Gender</th>

                        <th>Term
                        <select id="filterText"  onchange='filterText()'>
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="Fall2018">Fall2018</option> 
                              <option value="Srping2019">Spring2019</option>
                        </select></th>
                    <th> Action </th>

                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <?php
            if (count($report) === 0) {
                echo "<tr>No Reports</tr>";
            } else {

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($report); $i++) {

                    echo

                    "<tr class='row'>

                        <td>{$report[$i]['FName']}</td>
                        <td>{$report[$i]['LName']}</td>
                        <td>{$report[$i]['HPhone']}</td>
                        <td>{$report[$i]['PEmail']}</td>
                        <td>{$report[$i]['Gender']}</td>
                        <td>{$report[$i]['Term']}</td>

                        <td><a class=btn href='read.php?id=".$report[$i]['RegId']."'>Read</a></td>  

                    </tr>";

                }
            }



            ?>
        </table>
```

main.js

```
function filterText()
    {  
        var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val());
        if(rex ==="/all/"){clearFilter();}else{
            $('.row').show();
            $('.row').filter(function() {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).hide();
    }
    }

   function clearFilter()
    {
        $('.filterText').val('');
        $('.row').show();
    }
```

I'm adding the dropdown filter to the term column. This code gives the opposite results. Like when I click on the 'All' option of the dropdown, it shows Spring2019 in the results. And when I click on the 'Spring2019' it shows all the values. And 'Fall2018' also shows all the Spring2019 values.

Can you check what is wrong in the code?

Comment: If you ask a JavaScript question, you should add HTML *instead of* PHP.

Comment: Yeah okay but this is what I've tried. Can you see any error? Why is it giving the opposite results

Comment: If you have PHP you have the generated HTML. You can add it in a snippet, to make it easier for those who wish to help you. Considering the code you have exposed - PHP, whoever wants to help has to run int on a server.

Comment: this statement here will never be true.  if(rex ==="/all/").  You are using === which also compares type equality.  One is a RegExp object and the other is a string.  Therefore that will never be true.  I would recommend changing to compare the value of the control instead of the regexp

Comment: Can you edit it for me please? I'm very new to JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salam,
 i think you can filter by cell text instead of row text, just add class to your cell

```
<td>{$report[$i]['Term']}</td>
```

like that

```
<td class='term'>{$report[$i]['Term']}</td>
```

and change your search function to

```js
function filterText()
    {  
        var val = $('#filterText').val().toLowerCase();
        if(val === "")
           return;
        if(val === "all")
          clearFilter();
        else
        $('.term').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase() === val);
            });

    }
```

Comment: Hey, tried this, it only works for fall2018 and when I click on Spring2019, the values disappear. All doesn't work either. The values disappear.

Comment: salam, i make some changes now try it and tell me if you need more help

Comment: Heyy, thanks.. now the fall2018 and spring2019 are working completely fine. Just the All is giving only fall2018 values.

Answer (score 0):

Salam, there are no problem in my side, try run this snippet here and you'll see that it work fine just find what is the deference in you generated html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function filterText()
    {  
        var val = $('#filterText').val().toLowerCase();
        if(val === "")
           return;
        if(val === "all")
          clearFilter();
        else
        $('.term').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase() === val);
            });

    }
   function clearFilter()
    {
        $('.filterText').val('');
        $('.row').show();
    }
</script>

<table id ="myTable" class="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> First Name </th>
                    <th> Last Name </th>                  
                    <th> Phone </th>
                    <th> Email </th>              
                    <th> Gender</th>

                        <th>Term
                        <select id="filterText"  onchange='filterText()'>
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="Fall2018">Fall2018</option> 
                              <option value="Srping2019">Spring2019</option>
                        </select></th>
                    <th> Action </th>

                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>             
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td>
            <td class="term">something</td>
            <td><a class=btn href=''>Read</a></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td>
            <td class="term">Fall2018</td>
            <td><a class=btn href=''>Read</a></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td>
            <td class="term">Spring2019</td>
            <td><a class=btn href=''>Read</a></td>  
            </tr>
            
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```